# React-Native Dynamic Array from Server

Tags: javascript, mysql, react-native

How can I get JSON file from Web API (Server)? I have this code and Dynamic Array from Server has a problem. Could anybody help me please?

Searchable Dropdown from Dynamic Array from Server => This line has a problem, it doesn't work. How can we get the correct solution of this question?

I don't have any idea of solution.

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our project
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
//import basic react native components
import SearchableDropdown from 'react-native-searchable-dropdown';
//import SearchableDropdown component

//Item array for the dropdown
var items = [
  //name key is must.It is to show the text in front
  { id: 1, name: 'angellist' },
  { id: 2, name: 'codepen' },
  { id: 3, name: 'envelope' },
  { id: 4, name: 'etsy' },
  { id: 5, name: 'facebook' },
  { id: 6, name: 'foursquare' },
  { id: 7, name: 'github-alt' },
  { id: 8, name: 'github' },
  { id: 9, name: 'gitlab' },
  { id: 10, name: 'instagram' },
];
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      serverData: [],
      //Data Source for the SearchableDropdown
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://aboutreact.000webhostapp.com/demo/webservice/demosearchables.php')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        //Successful response from the API Call
        this.setState({
          serverData: [...this.state.serverData, ...responseJson.results],
          //adding the new data in Data Source of the SearchableDropdown
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 30 }}>
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
          Searchable Dropdown from Static Array
        </Text>
        <SearchableDropdown
          onTextChange={text => console.log(text)}
          //On text change listner on the searchable input
          onItemSelect={item => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}
          //onItemSelect called after the selection from the dropdown
          containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
          //suggestion container style
          textInputStyle={{
            //inserted text style
            padding: 12,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#ccc',
            backgroundColor: '#FAF7F6',
          }}
          itemStyle={{
            //single dropdown item style
            padding: 10,
            marginTop: 2,
            backgroundColor: '#FAF9F8',
            borderColor: '#bbb',
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}
          itemTextStyle={{
            //single dropdown item's text style
            color: '#222',
          }}
          itemsContainerStyle={{
            //items container style you can pass maxHeight
            //to restrict the items dropdown hieght
            maxHeight: '60%',
          }}
          items={items}
          //mapping of item array
          defaultIndex={2}
          //default selected item index
          placeholder="placeholder"
          //place holder for the search input
          resetValue={false}
          //reset textInput Value with true and false state
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          //To remove the underline from the android input
        />
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
          Searchable Dropdown from Dynamic Array from Server
        </Text>
        <SearchableDropdown
          onTextChange={text => console.log(text)}
          //On text change listner on the searchable input
          onItemSelect={item => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}
          //onItemSelect called after the selection from the dropdown
          containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
          //suggestion container style
          textInputStyle={{
            //inserted text style
            padding: 12,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#ccc',
            backgroundColor: '#FAF7F6',
          }}
          itemStyle={{
            //single dropdown item style
            padding: 10,
            marginTop: 2,
            backgroundColor: '#FAF9F8',
            borderColor: '#bbb',
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}
          itemTextStyle={{
            //single dropdown item's text style
            color: '#222',
          }}
          itemsContainerStyle={{
            //items container style you can pass maxHeight
            //to restrict the items dropdown hieght
            maxHeight: '50%',
          }}
          items={this.state.serverData}
          //mapping of item array
          defaultIndex={2}
          //default selected item index
          placeholder="placeholder"
          //place holder for the search input
          resetValue={false}
          //reset textInput Value with true and false state
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          //To remove the underline from the android input
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to render conditionally, `{ this.state.serverData && this.state.serverData.length > 0 && <SearchableDropdown ... />}`

Comment: I am not understanding this answer, could you try again ?

Comment: Check this -https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Brother, full text link i can't find yours answer

Comment: First, this doc is not written by me. Second, I have provided a doc for reference, you need to read and understood the concept of conditonal rendering.

Comment: First, i dont have enough english for document. Second, you dont understand me, you cant help me thank you see you soon....